# How to prove bounds of area integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ and $D = \{(x,y)|x^2+1 \le y \le 2\}$, show that $$\frac43 \le\int_D f(x,y)dA\le\frac{20}{3}$$

How would you solve this question?

Comment: Computing the integral does not require more work than verifying these estimates. Note that they differ by a factor of $5$, hence at least one of them has to be **very** bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint :  For every  $(x,y)$ in D (From the plot)

[image]

$$ 1  \le   f(x,y)  = x^2+y^2 \le  y -1 +y^2 \le  2-1+4 =5  $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint. First make a drawing of the domain $D$ (or look at Nizar's plot).

Then evaluate the area of $D$:
$$\mbox{Area}(D)=\int_{x=-1}^1\int_{y=x^2+1}^2dA=2\int_{x=0}^1(1-x^2)dx
=\frac{4}{3}.$$
Now consider the points $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ (or $(-1,2)$).

What are the squared distances of  $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ from the origin?

What may we conclude?